# Color selected by user as "drawing color"

Tags: javascript

With the web app that i have here, the user needs to hand select the color's. And i have a limit of the colors that are usable. i want to have a color-picker that the user can use to select the drawing color. but i dont get it to work.

[My webapp so far...](https://projectmediavormgeving.github.io/Files/Samir/paint.html)

```js
var started = false;
var canvas, context;
var stampId = '';
var lastColor = 'black';
var lastStampId = '';
var enableDraw = false;

function init() {
    canvas = $('#imageView').get(0);
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Auto-adjust canvas size to fit window.
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 75;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 75;

    //$('#container').get(0).addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        enableDraw = true;
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
        enableDraw = false;
        started = false;
    }, false);

    // Add events for toolbar buttons.
    $('#red').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onColorClick(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#pink').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onColorClick(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#fuchsia').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onColorClick(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#orange').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onColorClick(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#yellow').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onColorClick(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#lime').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onColorClick(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#green').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onColorClick(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#blue').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onColorClick(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#purple').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onColorClick(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#black').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onColorClick(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#white').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onColorClick(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#cat').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onStamp(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#dragonfly').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onStamp(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#ladybug').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onStamp(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#heart').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onStamp(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#dog').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onStamp(e.target.id);
    }, false);
    $('#fill').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onFill();
    }, false);
    $('#save').get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        onSave();
    }, false);
}

function onMouseMove(ev) {
    var x, y;

    // Get the mouse position.
    if (ev.layerX >= 0) {
        // Firefox
        x = ev.layerX - 0;
        y = ev.layerY - 0;
    }
    else if (ev.offsetX >= 0) {
        // Opera
        x = ev.offsetX - 0;
        y = ev.offsetY - 0;
    }

    if (enableDraw && stampId.length === 0) {
        if (!started) {
            started = true;
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(x, y);
        }
        else {
            context.lineTo(x, y);
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

    $('#stats').text('x ' + x + ', ' + 'y ' + y);
    $('#size').text('width ' + canvas.width + ', ' + 'height' + canvas.height);
}

function onClick(e) {
    if (stampId.length > 0) {
        context.drawImage($(stampId).get(0), e.pageX - 90, e.pageY - 60, 80, 80);
    }
}

function onColorClick(color) {
    // Start a new path to begin drawing in a new color.
    context.closePath();
    context.beginPath();

    // Select the new color.
    context.strokeStyle = color;

    // Highlight selected color.
    var borderColor = 'white';
    if (color === 'white' || color === 'yellow') {
        borderColor = 'black';
    }

    $('#' + lastColor).css("border", "0px dashed white");
    $('#' + color).css("border", "1px dashed " + borderColor);

    // Store color so we can un-highlight it next time around.
    lastColor = color;

    // Turn off any stamp selection, since we're painting again.
    $(stampId).css("border", "0px dashed white");
    stampId = '';
}

function onFill() {
    // Start a new path to begin drawing in a new color.
    context.closePath();
    context.beginPath();

    context.fillStyle = context.strokeStyle;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function onStamp(id) {
    // Update the stamp image.
    stampId = '#' + id;

    if (lastStampId === stampId) {
        // User clicked the selected stamp again, so deselect it.
        stampId = '';
    }

    $(lastStampId).css("border", "0px dashed white");
    $(stampId).css("border", "1px dashed black");

    $('#' + lastColor).css("border", "0px dashed white");

    // Store stamp so we can un-highlight it next time around.
    lastStampId = stampId;
}

function onSave() {
    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream.png");
    window.location.href=image;
}
```

```css
/**
 *  Created somewhere on the Bahama's.
 *    __̴ı̴̴̡̡̡ ̡͌l̡̡̡ ̡͌l̡*̡̡ ̴̡ı̴̴̡ ̡̡͡|̲̲̲͡͡͡ ̲▫̲͡ ̲̲̲͡͡π̲̲͡͡ ̲̲͡▫̲̲͡͡ ̲|̡̡̡ ̡ ̴̡ı̴̡̡ ̡͌l̡̡̡̡.___
 *  By Samir.
 */
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#imageView {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

div#canvasDiv {
    cursor: crosshair;
}

div {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Paint</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="paint.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="init.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="padding:5px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <div id="colorToolbar" style="border: 1px solid black; float: left;">
        <div id="red" style="background: red; width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="pink" style="background:pink; width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="fuchsia" style="background:fuchsia; width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="orange" style="background:orange; width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="yellow" style="background:yellow; width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="lime" style="background:lime; width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="green" style="background:green; width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="blue" style="background:blue; width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="purple" style="background:purple; width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="black" style="background:black; width:50px; height:50px; float:left; border: 1px dashed white;"></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="white" style="background:white; width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <hr/>
        <div id="fill" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"><img src="img/fill.png" width="50" height="50"/>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="cat" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"><img id="catImg" src="img/cat.png" width="50"
                                                                        height="50"/></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="dog" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"><img id="dogImg" src="img/dog.png" width="50"
                                                                        height="50"/></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="dragonfly" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"><img id="dragonFlyImg" src="img/fly.png"
                                                                              width="50" height="50"/></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="ladybug" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"><img id="ladyBugImg" src="img/bug.png" width="50"
                                                                            height="50"/></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="heart" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"><img id="heartImg" src="img/heart.png" width="50"
                                                                          height="50"/></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="save" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left;"><a id="download" download="image.png">Save</a></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="canvasDiv" style="float: left;">
        <canvas id="imageView">
            <p>Unfortunately, your browser is currently unsupported by our web
                application. We are sorry for the inconvenience. Please use one of the
                supported browsers listed below, or draw the image you want using an
                offline tool.</p>
            <p>Supported browsers: <a href="http://www.opera.com">Opera</a>, <a
                    href="http://www.mozilla.com">Firefox</a>, <a
                    href="http://www.apple.com/safari">Safari</a>, and <a
                    href="http://www.konqueror.org">Konqueror</a>.</p>
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="stats" style="font-size:8pt; padding-left: 50px; float: left;">0 0</div>
    <div id="size" style="font-size:8pt; padding-left: 500px; float: left;">0 0</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone insert a working colorpicker in my code?
like this : [image]

Comment: Create a code-snippet using `<>` including the minimum relevant code so that we can replicate the issue and help you resolving the same.

Comment: use this [colorpicker](http://www.jar2.net/projects/jquery-wheelcolorpicker)

Comment: i have added the code